# WooZone WordPress Configuration issues

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have installed WooZone Plugin to catch the Products from Amazon.
I have configured the WooZone perfectly. But Now it is showing me some kind error when i try to Search the Products.

(Amazon error id: AWS.InvalidAccount: 
Your AccessKey Id is not registered for Product Advertising API. Please use the AccessKey Id obtained after registering at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/advertising/api/sign-in.html)

I dont know how to fix it. But i have to do it must. I am failing again and again.

Please help me Experts.

Comment: Well did you try and get an access key as the error states?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AccessKey` Id is not registered for Product Advertising API.

Please use the AccessKey Id obtained after registering [here](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/advertising/api/sign-in.html)